# Spring boot jpa transaction cannot insert on exception

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have the code shown below, I am not able to insert into error table when the exception occurs in spring jpa transaction. The exception is thrown in method insertInTwoTables is catched and I would like to insert some data in error table. Please help.

```
public class MyClass {

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void createSomething() {
        try {
            insertInTwoTables();
            // Exception occurs in insertInTwoTables, I want to rollback this method 
               insertInTwoTables updates
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Since error has occurred I want to insert this information
            // into a error table

            errorInsert();

        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void insertInTwoTables() {
  }

    @Transactional
    public void errorInsert() {
  }

}
```

Comment: What is keeping you from inserting it into the error table?

Answer (score 1):

In situations like this I found success in putting errorInsert in another class which you can inject with spring. Make sure this method has transactional annotation set to REQUIRES_NEW so whatever may have botched the operational transaction is avoided as the errorInsert will get it's own fresh transaction.

Here is a page I found that touches on errors and requires new for additional background.

https://www.netsurfingzone.com/spring/transactional-required-vs-requires_new-example-in-spring-boot/